# Financial year Statement for All Fiscal year (April to March) in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, pivot-table

Where can I generate the Financial year report for last 10 years dynamically like this using T-sql:

```
Months |2007-2008 |2008-2009|   2009-2010 |2010-2011 | Average
-------------------------------------------------------------------
April                       
May                                 
June                                    
July                                    
August                                  
September                                   
October                                 
November                                    
December                                    
January                                 
February                                    
March                                   
Average
```

Comment: We need your table structure with sample data to be of any help

Comment: ID, Year, Month, Expense, Datetime, monthorder where my SQL table columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what [DATETIME] represents, I'm assuming it is a indicator of month or year year, if not you 'll need to change the where statements to incorporate YEAR and MONTH.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT '2007-2008' AS FISCALYEAR, SUM(EXPENSE) AS EXPENSE
FROM YOURTABLE
WHERE [DATETIME] BETWEEN '4/1/2007' AND '3/31/2008'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2008-2009' AS FISCALYEAR, SUM(EXPENSE) AS EXPENSE
FROM YOURTABLE
WHERE [DATETIME] BETWEEN '4/1/2008' AND '3/31/2009'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2009-2010' AS FISCALYEAR, SUM(EXPENSE) AS EXPENSE
FROM YOURTABLE
WHERE [DATETIME] BETWEEN '4/1/2009' AND '3/31/2010'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2010-2011' AS FISCALYEAR, SUM(EXPENSE) AS EXPENSE
FROM YOURTABLE
WHERE [DATETIME] BETWEEN '4/1/2010' AND '3/31/2011'
```

That should get you close to getting the expense for each fiscal year.  To get the average, just do the same and aggregate it.